# Is it a historical coincidence that relative atomic weights by chemical methods and mass spectrometry are very close?

Tags: physics, terminology, discoveries, philosophy-of-science, chemistry

The concept of relative atomic weight originated from measuring the combining weight of hydrogen with a certain element. In the simplification process H was taken as unity (18th, 19th and 20th century). For example from combining weights of hydrogen and oxygen, one can show that the weight of oxygen is almost 16 times more than H. Chemists did not have any means to measure absolute masses.

Now when Aston invented the mass spectrometer in 1940s, he also measured atomic masses. Aston's book is available here https://archive.org/details/in.ernet.dli.2015.205751/page/n14

1) As per my understanding, a mass spectrometer can measure the *absolute mass* based on charge-to-mass ratio. Provided we know the charge on the ion which is usually one, one can determine the absolute mass without any regard to chemical principles, purely on the principles of electricity and magnetism. I am wondering how come the current masses measured by chemical means turn out to be almost the same, *in terms of numerical values*, as measured by an independent instrument such as a mass spectrometer. For example, O-16 isotope is still 16 by MS measurements?

2) Why don't we quote absolute atomic weights given that modern FT-Ion Cyclotron MS can detect extremely delicate mass changes?

Thanks.

Comment: Isn't this because most elements studied in the early 19th century were nearly mono-isotopic?

Comment: No, this is not the case, by early 1920s, Theodore Richards (Nobel) has determined atomic weights of most elements.

Comment: I'm puzzled by your comment: the 1920s were not in the 19th century.  Is your question a historical one at all?

Comment: I can't really answer your question, but I'd say it's no coincidence. It's because both are getting at the "underlying truth" as it were. You probably know about it already, but see [Prout's hypothesis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prout%27s_hypothesis): _"he observed that the atomic weights that had been measured for the elements known at that time appeared to be whole multiples of the atomic weight of hydrogen. He then hypothesized that the hydrogen atom was the only truly fundamental object, which he called protyle..."_

Comment: John, Prout's hypothesis was discarded when very precise measurements could not reconcile with the multiple of hydrogen weight. I am wondering why mass spectrometers needed a "relative" atomic weight? The e/m ratio should give a precise mass of the ion.

Comment: Despite the name, setting ion charge to 1 is no more "absolute" than setting hydrogen weight to 1, and weight to weight ratios are dimensionless, so more "absolute". Also, "chemical principles" ultimately derive from electromagnetic interactions (and mechanics), so why is it surprising that the numbers match when the same thing is properly measured in two different ways? How is it different from the same distances being measured by rulers and lasers?

Comment: Since both are evaluating the same physical parameter(s), how could they not be very close?

Comment: The reason we don't quote absolute atomic masses (not weight!) is because, although tables of the isotopes are easy to find, I can't remember the 5 or 6 decimal places of each isotope, so we round to the nearest easy-to-remember integer. Further, note that your mass spectrometer still needs either (1) magnetic field measurement, or (2) distance measurement for time-of-flight, so it is not 'absolute' until calibrated.

Comment: Chemists used atomic masses/ weights interchangeably. It is, of course, understood that atomic mass is being referred. I agree, all instruments need calibration but that cannot be the sole reason as to why mass spectrometrists needed to do relative measurements of atomic masses. I feel (no proof) that Aston relied on then known atomic mass of O and set it to 16 (exactly) for calibration of his photographic plates or detector. Electron's mass is not quoted with respect to any reference, why atoms needed a reference? Today it is carbon 12, where 12 is set arbitrarily to 12.0000000 (ad infinitum)